# Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface : Private static IP address does not belong to the range of subnet prefix

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have recently created a virtual machine in Azure where I have installed WordPress and MySQL in it. I have created a Web App too. Now I need to assign my static Web App IP address to the Virtual machine I created. I tried the following commands but no luck there.

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName IP –Location "South Central US" -ServiceName ServName
```

I am using latest Azure Powershell in my virtual machine. When I search for a solution people are saying the commands I used are not compatible with the latest powershell. So I used the commands explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-ps/) as follows.

```
$nic=Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name networkinterfacename -ResourceGroupName resouorcegrpupname $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAllocationMethod = 'Static' $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAddress = 'ip address' Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

But when I run I am getting error as 
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface : Private static IP address does not belong to the range of subnet prefix 10.0.0.0/24.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note : I have logged in to the Powershell and I am able to run the commands Add-AzureAccount, Select-AzureSubscription, Get-AzureStorageAccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Private static IP address does not belong to the range of subnet prefix 10.0.0.0/24.

This error message has clearly described the root cause of this issue. I suppose that the static IP address doesn't reside in the subnet 10.0.0.0/24.

You have two options to overcome this issue:

1. Change the static IP address. (Choose an available IP from the subnet 10.0.0.0/24)
2. Create a new subnet which contains your static IP address.

Note: All the subnets must belong to same VNET. Azure doesn't support move the VM to another VNET.

Here is a good [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/03/13/how-to-change-subnet-and-virtual-network-for-azure-virtual-machines-asm-arm/) about how to move the VMs between the subnets.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the information. Actually I have created a WebApp and configured the CNAME, and it is working http://techtrivandrum.com/. Now I have created a new virtual machine and installed WordPress and MySQL in it, now what I need is, to map the WordPress with the WebApp, so whenever I click http://techtrivandrum.com/ the WordPress site can be seen. For what are all the things I need to set. Sorry if I am confusing you. Thank you.

Comment: Does your VM have a public IP address? If yes, then all you need is that edit the DNS record to point techtrivandrum.com to the public IP address of your VM. To get the public IP address of your VM, use this command: "Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | select Name,IpAddress"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You are saying about the A name configuration in DNS manager right? So if I set it, will the WordPress site be shown when I browse the URL techtrivandrum.com?

Comment: @SibeeshVenu Another thing need to be mentioned is that please use the preserved public IP address for your VM. So that it won't be changed when you deallocate the VM.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu You need to configure the wildcard A record like *.techtrivandrum.com and point it to the public IP address of your VM. Also, you need to wait for several hours to let the record be replicated over the world.

Comment: Hi Thanks much for the information, can you please help me to find out whether there is any reserved IP address for my VM, if there is no such IP, I must create it right? And once It is created, I must assign that reserved IP to the A name right? Please clarify my doubts, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can see in the commands I tried already is for creating the reserved Ip as you suggested, but while doing so I am getting the error as mentioned in the question. Please check that, it would be great if you can share any idea on this. Thank you.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu If you create your VM in resource manager mode. Then please use the following command to create a new reserved public IP: "New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name ipname -ResourceGroupName groupname -Location yourlocaltion -AllocationMethod Static -IpAddressVersion IPv4"

Comment: @SibeeshVenu To find if an IP address is static assigned，just add a column: "Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | select Name,IpAddress,PublicIpAllocationMethod"

Comment: Hi Thanks much, I run the first command and the IP allocation method is changed to static, and when I run the second command Ip allocation method shows as null. Now I need to give this IP address to the DNS A record right?

Comment: @SibeeshVenu Before you edit the DNS settings, you should assign this public IP address to the VM.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I am totally new to this area. If you don't mind, can you please give me some tips to that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the Azure Powershell commands, I would suggest you to deploy the WordPress with a template. Here is a good guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-create-web-app-from-marketplace/

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look into it. You really helped me a lot. Much appreciated. I will accept your answer now.